# tf.loadModel is not a function

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I am Classifying images using Keras MobileNet and TensorFlow.js in Google Chrome.I followed a tutorial. when i run the code i got the tf.loadModel is not a function error.
 I load the model like this.

```html
 model = await tf.loadModel('https://gogul09.github.io/models/mobilenet/model.json');
 model.predict();
```

[image: error details]

Comment: tf.load_model??

Comment: sorry ,what are you asking?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're observing the error because the tf.loadModel API has changed in the recent versions of tensorflow.js. I could get the prediction working by doing the following changes in the project https://github.com/Gogul09/digit-recognizer-live:

In **index.html**, change the version to 0.10.0 instead of latest.

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.0"></script>
```

After doing this change, I got one more error: *"Argument 'b' passed to 'div' must be a Tensor, but got number."*

To fix this, in **app.js**, function preprocessCanvas() change tensor.div(255.0)  to

`tensor.div(tf.scalar(255.0))`

Depending on whether you're using MLP or CNN model make the change accordingly. Reload the page, once you change the js file.

For this project, https://github.com/Gogul09/mobile-net-projects, after hard-coding the tf js version, the prediction didn't work because the click event of the predict button was not getting triggered. Also, for Upload Image. After replacing these lines in **mobile-net.js**, prediction works.

Change

```
$("#predict-button").click(async function () {
```

to

```
$(document).on('click', '#predict-button', async function() {
```

Change

```
$("#select-file-image").change(function() {
```

to

```
$(document).on('change', '#select-file-image', function() {
```

Comment: I changed <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.10.0"></script> like this .still no error but i can not able to predict .

Comment: i am getting DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGL2RenderingContext': The image element contains cross-origin data, and may not be loaded. error

Comment: I tried only with demo image option. When are you getting this error? Also, I downloaded the code to my laptop and opened index html in the browser.

Comment: This works on Firefox. On chrome, I see the error you mention. Meanwhile, can you please check if it works on Firefox?

Comment: Updated the answer for upload image.

Comment: hello sir,How to train my own dataset in mobilenet. Can you please share any tutorial ??

Answer (score 23):

The function loadModel has been renamed to loadLayersModel.

Comment: this one line really helped me